# Java regular expression match compare operator

Tags: java, regex

I need to have a regular expression to match something like this

```
key>value
key=value
key.subkey>=value
```

Here is my regular expression

```
([a-zA-Z]*\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z]*)([=|>|<|>=|<=]{1})(.*)
```

it works for most of the cases, but except for >=, and <=

Example:

```
test>=123

Group
0   test>=123
1   test
2   >
3   =123
```

how do i specify that the last group doesnt starts with special characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
([a-zA-Z]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)?)([<>]=|[=><])(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZIxFH/1)

**Details**

- `([a-zA-Z]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z]+)?)` - Group 1: 1+ ASCII letters followed with an optional sequence of a dot and 1+ ASCII letters
- `([<>]=|[=><])` - Group 2: `<` or `>` and then `=`, or a `=`, `<`, or `>` (**so the longer ones, `<=` or `>=` are tried first**)
- `(.*)` - Group 3: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.